# How do you use the output of one servlet inside another servlet's init() method?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    // ...
    URL url = new URL("http://myhost:port/path/to/otherservlet");
    // ... do stuff with contents of url
}
```

This works fine, but myhost and port are hardcoded and I want to avoid that. I want

```
URL url = new URL("/path/to/otherservlet");
```

but that's not valid. I've also tried

```
config.getServletContext().getResource("/path/to/otherservlet");
```

but that only works on static files.

How can I use the result of getting one servlet to initialize another? I don't want to use RequestDispatcher's forward() or include() methods -- the results of otherservlet are intended for use in the init() method, not to be sent in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised to find that it can't be done. I think toby's answer (split the code out into a common class) is the best approach, but if that's really not possible, try encoding the host and port to be used for local requests as context parameters in the server's `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>localhost</param-name>
    <param-value>localhost</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>localport</param-name>
    <param-value>8080</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and get the values with `context.getInitParameter("localhost")` etc. You could also try to determine the values dynamically, but you might have to wait for a request to come in so you can use something like `HttpUtils.getRequestURL(req)` - I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: That's kind of the conclusion I was reaching as well, but I was hoping it wouldn't be so.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I think the better approach is to refactor the code for the other servlet into a class somewhere that can be called directly for the output that you need.

Comment: Let's say that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'd work if you prepend that URL with the servlet context.

I agree that a refactoring sounds like a better idea.  If it's an init operation, and both servlets are in the same context, perhaps the parameters can be externalized to a file or database in such a way that both can pick them up.

I wouldn't like an init to be too extensive.